# How can I find a post I believe was deleted?

Tags: support, search, deleted-questions

I posted, *possibly* on softwareengineering.stackexchange.com, a question saying that a couple of recent bits of breakage on my Mac made me wonder if Apple was still being warm and fuzzy to the Unix community. (One was problematically frequent Terminal.app crashes; I don't remember the other one.) I believe the question was closed and possibly deleted as out of scope.

I would like to have what I wrote available for a blog post not intended to be under the Stack Exchange umbrella, but I'm having difficulty locating it; egosearches under apple.stackexchange.com and softwareengineering.stackexchange.com do not seem to show this post, and Google egosearches (`site:stackexchange.com JonathanHayward Terminal.app`) do not appear to show my post.

Am I correct in guessing that the post is not turning in searches because it was deemed off-topic? Is there any way any of the moderators here could fish it up?

Comment: This one: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/270509/terminal-has-been-unstable-since-last-upgrade-osx-10-12-2/271936 ?

Comment: Depending on when you posted it you can: 1) check your browser history, 2) use sede to find it, or 3) click "deleted recent questions" in your profile at the bottom of the question list to find it. Or if it's not deleted but you just lost it but posted it relatively recently you can check your network wide activity history on stackexchange.com, although it only goes back a limited time.

Comment: Or do you mean this one: https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8477/looking-for-where-to-post-is-apple-tacitly-declaring-independence-indifferenc/8478

Comment: @JasonC it looks like the OP doesn't know which site they posted on in the first place.

Comment: Btw @Jonathan those Apple ones (if those are the ones you're looking for) also show up in https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackexchange.com+"JonathanHayward"+Terminal.app

Comment: How long time was it up (minutes, hours, days, months, years)? Sometimes [Wayback Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayback_Machine) can help.

Comment: @rene Thank you. it was the second post you found. Could you writeup an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @JonathanHayward : I just used [this search](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A65767+terminal.app) and got 1 hit ... the question you seem to be looking for. Not sure if 'I' am allowed to post an answer (since you asked rene to do so ...). What do you think? PS: the search keywords themselves are just like this (without the quotes): "**user:65767 terminal.app**". That is: "give me any (non-deleted) post for user 65767, in which you find a string "terminal.app" ... ***Easy, no?***

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens be my guest to answer, I'm not interested.

Comment: @rene merci for the *approval* ... fingers crossed that I'm close to how you did it ...

Answer (score 3):

If you use [this search](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A65767+terminal.app) you'll get 1 hit ... i.e [the question you seem to be looking for](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8477/173670).

The search keywords themselves are just like this:

```
user:65767 terminal.app
```

That is: list all (non-deleted) posts for **`user 65767`**, in which you find a string **`terminal.app`**.

---

#### Bonus tips:

---

1. Recommended reading: [Advanced search options](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching).
2. Build some sort of search result, such as a simple "[is:Q](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq)". Then use the link (upper right) that says <kbd>Advanced Search Tips</kbd> to open up some kind of cheatsheet, which will show dozens of search options such as this part of it:

   > ```
   > status closed:yes
   >        duplicate:no
   >        migrated:no
   >        wiki:no
   >        deleted:no
   > ```
3. Special cases:

   - that `deleted:no` only show ups (+ is only allowed to be used) if you have "sufficient" reputation. I.e. `10K` (credits to [Laurel](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/323179/laurel)) for graduated sites  (`2K` for beta sites), and as detailed also in the [Access To Moderator Tools](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) (within "Viewing deleted posts"). In my case, it is not shown on meta.SE, while I do get it on some other SE site where I have the privilege to use it.
   - Special case (bis): if I use `deleted:yes` (on the site where I'm allowed to use it), it shows an extra informational note like "`Note: only content you own is returned when searching for deleted content`". And the result I get is the list of "my" questions that have status deleted. If I do the very same query on meta.SE (where I don't have the privilege needed) I get no such "note", and a result that simply ignores the `deleted:yes` (so just all questions).

PS: Credits to [rene](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/158100/rene) for pointing to the question (url) you were looking for.

Comment: The `deleted` operator is a 10k privilege.

Comment: Merci @Laurel ... answer update (+ credits ...)

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens I believe you can still use "deleted:0" or "deleted:no" - but that's effectively the same search it would return by default anyway... I'm not sure, but there's also a "deleted:all" operator which will return both...

Comment: @JonClements what do you mean by that "still"?

Comment: ignore the "still"